# How can I format the date from mysql (I'm using node.js)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, datetime

I'm using node.js to select info from my mysql database and I have a datetime column, but I'm not getting the format I want.

This is my sql code
`SELECT id, data, titulo, subtitulo, texto, DATE(datahora_cadastro) as data FROM sig_noticias`

I need the data to be like this: `DD/MM/YYYY`
But I'm getting this: `Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to format dates in Javascript is by far using a modern date / time library. I personally use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) and it works well. I highly recommend this solution if you plan on working with dates in even just a few areas of your app.

Using moment, you could simply call `moment(myDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");`.

If you really want to stick to pure Javascript, however, here's how to get the format you want:

```
const formattedDate = `${myDate.getDate() + 1}/${myDate.getMonth() + 1}/${myDate.getFullYear()}`;
```

Javascript's built-in date functions are pretty confusing. Here, for instance, the `getDate` and `getMonth` methods return the index of the date / month, and not the actual date / month, so we need to add `+1` to those.

Using vanilla Javascript then becomes even harder when dealing with date manipulation (adding, subtracting) and timezones.

Comment: I'm sorry @FláviaNunes there was a typo in my format string. I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll use moment forever now haha

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString with suitable locale should do the trick e.g. `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString("en-GB")`.